# Porque al seleccionar una opción me direcciona bien, pero me pinta de color otra opción en la que no estoy

Tags: javascript, php

[image: Selecciono incidencias y si me manda al apartado de incidencias, pero me pinta de color azul tareas como si hubiera seleccionado ese]**Selecciono incidencias y si me manda al apartado de incidencias, pero me pinta de color azul tareas como si hubiera seleccionado ese.**

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="index" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'tarea/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <p>
  Tareas
  </p>
  </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
  <a id="index" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'incidencia/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-paste"></i>
  <p>
  Incidencias
  </p>
  </a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a id="index" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'parcial/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-chalkboard"></i>
  <p>
```

Comment: que framework estas usando?

Comment: @John estoy ocupando laravel

Comment: en laravel con adminlte se seleciona por la URL si estas usando un metodo del controlador tareas para tu formulario este va a verse selecionado, o cuando colocas el mismo item sin editar las opciones del array menu del adminlte

Comment: | https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/#83-custom-menu-filters

Answer (score 0):

Los `<a>` de tus `<li>` tienen los mismos id, esto puede generar conflicto, a la hora de ir a buscar que id realizo la acción encuentra al primero y ese selecciona porque se supone son únicos

Podrías ponerlo así:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <a id="li_item_1" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'tarea/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
  <p>
  Tareas
  </p>
  </a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
  <a id="li_item_2" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'incidencia/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-paste"></i>
  <p>
  Incidencias
  </p>
  </a>
  </li>
  
  <li class="nav-item">
  <a id="li_item_3" name="index" href="' . constant('URL') . 'parcial/index" class="nav-link">
  <i class="nav-icon fas fa-chalkboard"></i>
  <p>
```

Los name también los repites, aunque no sabría si en un `<a>` esto afecte, te recomendaría no repitas ese tipo de datos únicos